# have/teach classes

Tags: word-choice

If I can't be at work and have classes with my group, and I wan't to ask my colleague to substitute for me. Can I ask:

Can you **have classes** with my group?

Can you **teach** my classes?

Thank you!

Comment: In the UK, 'Can you please take my classes tomorrow?' would be the normal way of putting this. 'Can you please cover my classes tomorrow(?)' could also be used, but would normally be addressed to the person whose job it was to arrange cover. Questions like this are probably better asked on the sister site, ELL, Manolya.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think that 'have classes' would mean attending classes as a student whereas in this case the correct usage would be 'teach' my classes.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. While this is true in general conversation, among instructors it's not at all uncommon to say *I have class* (or *I have a class*) to indicate that they will attend class— though to teach, rather than learn. It is analogous to *having an appointment*, and so a chef might excuse herself because she *has dinner at 5* (to prepare, not consume), a director because he *has rehearsal at 5* (to direct, not rehearse himself), and so on.